# Provided certificate and key as part of SSL handshake

Tags: java, ssl, mutual-authentication

I have a java 8 which sends web requests outbound to a server that requires mutual authentication. I can connect using a curl command and passing the following arguments

```
--cacert ./cert.pem --cert server.crt --key server.key
```

What do I do with these crt pem and key files to allow my JVM to use them on all outgoing requests?

Comment: See the JSSE Reference Guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that has trouble with this like I did.

1. The PEM goes into the TRUSTSTORE.
2. The crt and key file are combined to make a p12 file like so:

   ```
   openssl pkcs12 -export -in server.crt -inkey server.key -name [host] -out server.p12
   ```
3. Install your p12 into your KEYSTORE

   ```
   keytool -importkeystore -destkeystore keystore.jks -srckeystore server.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12
   ```

Comment: Alternitavely you can use the .p12 file as the keystore directly, as long as you specify `javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS12` or whatever it is.